# linq groupjoin using lambda with a where clause

Tags: linq, join, lambda

I need to add a join using Lambda if I have a further parameter available that will also be used in a where clause.

My problem is I'm not sure of the exact format for adding a new object MemberTagLysts and then how the where clause should be created.

```
    var tagList =   from t in dc.Tags
    join b in dc.Businesses on t.BusinessId equals b.BusinessId
            where t.IsActive == true
            where b.IsActive == true
            orderby t.AdImage descending
            select new TagItem
            {
                    tagName = t.Name.Replace("\"", ""),
                    tagImage = tagImagePath + t.AdImage.Replace("\"", ""),
                    tagDescription = t.Description.Replace("\"", "")
            };

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lystId))
            {
                            tagList = (IQueryable<TagItem>)tagList.GroupJoin(dc.MemberTagLysts, a => a.tagId, b => b.TagId, (a, b) => new { a, b });
            }
```

Comment: You should give us more context of your question. What is `MemberTagLysts`? What is the exptected output of your query? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
var tagList =   from t in dc.Tags
    join b in dc.Businesses on t.BusinessId equals b.BusinessId
    where t.IsActive
    where b.IsActive
    orderby t.AdImage descending
    select new TagItem
    {
            tagName = t.Name.Replace("\"", ""),
            tagImage = tagImagePath + t.AdImage.Replace("\"", ""),
            tagDescription = t.Description.Replace("\"", "")
    };

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lystId))
{
    tagList = tagList
             .GroupJoin(dc.MemberTagLysts.Where(l => l.lystId == lystId),
                        a => a.tagId,
                        b => b.TagId,
                        (a, b) => new { a, b }));
}
```

Conditionally expanding the query is good practice. Note that conditions like `where t.IsActive == true` are redundant, `where t.IsActive` is enough and arguable better readable with well-chosen property names (as you have).

Comment: Gert thanks, but with that code, I get this error... --> "CS1501: No overload for method 'Where' takes 4 arguments"